# What does labels in Disk Drill result mean?

Tags: recovery

What does labels in Disk Drill mean? "Existing files" is obvious, but what about the other ones? I can't find any explanation in the Net where there would be explained i.e. difference between "Reconstructed" and "Reconstructed labeled"

[image]

Comment: Have you asked Disk Drill developers?

Answer (score 1):

If the files you expected to find are not listed under "Found files",
search the "Reconstructed" and "Reconstructed labeled" sections of
the scan results.

In these sections you will find files that Disk Drill has reconstructed
based on known file signatures, but that do not have complete metadata
available.

You can preview the files to determine if they should be included in
the recovery.

Reference :
[Disk Drill Data Recovery Software](https://www.cleverfiles.com/data-recovery-software.html).

Answer (score 1):

"Reconstructed Labeled" are files with basic metadata.

Images may indicate what device or camera they were taken with, the image dimensions, some files have names.

"Reconstructed" are files without metadata, they are numbered and have the proper extension.

"Existing Files" are files that are not lost and still exist on your hard drive - all of this is obvious once you know it, not necessarily before.

Disk Drill's "manual" is an unwieldy online "knowledgebase" and the search bar brings up zero basic information on these items as they opted to not write "page one" of the documentation.

[There's a contact page here](https://www.cleverfiles.com/contacts.html%20) that also has a chat window that comes up.